# Purpose of this resistor in Arduino Nano schematic

Tags: arduino-nano, resistor

I was looking at the Arduino Nano's [schematic](http://download.arduino.org/products/NANO/Arduino%20Nano-Rev3.2-SCH.pdf) and noticed a resistor that seems to be pointless (RP2C on this picture).
[image: Strange resistor RP2C]
Also there is numbers 6 and 3 on it, does it mean that resistor is connected to pins 6 and 3 on FT232 or to the same pins on Atmega328?

Comment: I have very limited electric knowledge.. I seen on some circuits a small capacitor between VCC and GND (pins 6 and 3), but never a resistor without any other component in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an unused element of resistor array RP2. Both ends are grounded in order to reduce noise.

Comment: I get it now, thanks! And numbers represent pins of the resistor array.

Comment: What noise are you talking about?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, for better clarity: I think what you mean to say is: "***Because this resistor in the array is unused***, both ends are grounded in order to reduce noise." Right?

Answer (score 3):

The resistor is one of 4 resistors that make up an SMD resistor array, RP2. It is seen on the board here:
[image: Arduino Nano underside]

The resistor array works like this:
[image: Resistor array]

The resistor on this array is spare, so both terminals are grounded.

Comment: Can you please provide me any link regarding this resistor array,mine got faulty.I need to replace it!

Comment: The marking says `102` so that means each resistor in the array is 1k ohms. The size looks like a 1206 package. Digikey: https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/panasonic-electronic-components/EXB-V8V102JV/Y4102CT-ND/155159, RS/Allied: http://au.rs-online.com/web/p/array-resistors/5225406/, Farnel/Newark/Element14: http://au.element14.com/vishay/cra06p0831k00jta/resistor-resistor-array-1kohm/dp/1886553

Comment: Best answer: this part you said is key for my understanding: "The resistor on this array is spare, so both terminals are grounded."